# Visual Studio 2019 Python 2.7 debugging only printing first print statement

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to debug a simple python script I've written, but when using Python 2.7 [image] environment only the first line is printed in the debug output

```
thisThe thread 'MainThread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'pythonw.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

[image]

If I switch to a Python 3.8 environment [image] all the expected output is printed

```
this
is
just
a
bunch
of
text
that
should
print
The thread 'MainThread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'pythonw.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Is there a setting in VS 2019 that I can change to force the entire output to be displayed in the Output window?  Or have I somehow installed Python 2.7 incorrectly, or the Python Tools for VS?

I note that when I run this outside of VS it displays as expected.  I can confirm that the entire script runs, it's just not outputting the expected text to the window

Here is my test code

```
import time
print ("this")
print ("is")
print ("just")
print ("a")
print ("bunch")
print ("of")
print ("text")
print ("that")
print ("should")
print ("print")

time.sleep(5)
```

Running Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.0 on Windows 10 Pro.

Please note this is Visual Studio 2019, not VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to recreate your error as I'm on Linux, 64bit, and VScode 2020. However, I suspect it is some kind of concurrency issue wrapped up in the IDE. You can try breaking at the first line and stepping through to see if VScode wants to output all your `print` statements.

> I note that when I run this outside of VS it displays as expected.

I highly suggest you stick to this. VScode can get weird when you make it debug. In my experience, debugging machine learning programs with VScode and thousands of samples nearly crashes my system. I stick to the shell for consistent performance.

Comment: Please note this is Visual Studio, not VS Code.  But I'll give the break and step through a try to see what happens.

Comment: I set a break and stepped through - it went through each line of code as normal, but didn't print anything

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. Well, I'm not sure what it can be then. Good luck.